# Unable to install openssh-server on ubuntu 16.04 in Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, openssh

**I am running Docker for Mac, running the latest version `2.1.0.5`. My co-workers are running Docker on both Windows and Ubuntu with no issue.**

I have a Docker container with a brand new install of Ubuntu 16.04, I'm unable to install `openssh-server` successfully after installing `openssh-client`.

I made sure to follow the directions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html

The commands that I'm running are...

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get install -y --fix-missing openssh-server
```

Which results in the following error.

> E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/ncurses-term_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_all.deb Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]

I notice that the URL it's attempting to fetch the file from is `http://archive.ubuntu.com` instead of `us.archive.ubuntu.com`, I'm assuming that's okay but not sure why the difference.

I can successfully ping and navigate to `http://archive.ubuntu.com` in my browser.

> $ ping archive.ubuntu.com
>
> PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.173): 56 data bytes
>
> 64 bytes from 91.189.88.173: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=94.518 ms

I can successfully ping and navigate to `us.archive.ubuntu.com` in my browser.

> $ ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
>
> PING us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.24): 56 data bytes
>
> 64 bytes from 91.189.91.24: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=33.831 ms

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to ping if I leave off http://

Great answer to understand protocol: https://superuser.com/a/930503

At first, I would say it's an error from being behind a proxy but you seems to be able to ping those server. So DNS, check `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I remembered hearing that ping didn't work quite the same. I thought the proxy issue as well but I'm even able to go directly to the full URL and a file downloads via the browser... so I know the file is there.

Perhaps the issue is in `Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]`?